# Netbeans 12 "diff window" does not always highlight added or removed spaces in the code

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-12

I upgraded Netbenas 8 to Netbeans 12 and now my `diff window` does not always highlight added or removed spaces in the code.

It does highlight if spaces was added or removed in the middle of the line (after a non space character), and before a non space character.

But it does not highlight when the space was added or removed form the beginning of the line, or at the end of the line. Preceding and trailing spaces change does not get highlighted.

- I tried restarting Betbeans - it did not help.
- I checked HTML, PHP, TXT source code, all have the same problem.

Is there any config parameter to fix it, or is it a bug?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/3650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Diff**

By default, the checkbox **Ignore Leading and Trailing White Space** is checked:

[image: IgnoreSpaces]

Just uncheck the checkbox, then click the **OK** button. Diff will then report on leading and trailing space differences.

Comment: works for Netbeans-16 as well